# ng-message doesn't work for select boxes

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, ng-messages

i have a material design select and i'm trying validating it using ng-message

```
<md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm >
   <label>Payment method</label>
   <md-select name="paymentMethod"  ng-model="payment.paymentMethod" flex ng-change="paymentMethodChange(payment.paymentMethod)">
      <md-optgroup label="Payment Method">
      <md-option ng-repeat="item in PayArr track by $index" value="{{item}}">{{item}}</md-option>
   </md-select>
   <div ng-messages="editForm.paymentMethod.$error" >
      <div ng-message="required">payment method required</div>
   </div>
</md-input-container>
```

my form name is **editForm**. i use this same scenario for input boxes and it works fine. i can't figure out why it doesn't work for select box. thanks guys for ur support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't put the `required` attribute in `md-select`.

```
<md-select name="paymentMethod" required  ng-model="payment.paymentMethod" flex ng-change="paymentMethodChange(payment.paymentMethod)">
      <md-optgroup label="Payment Method">
      <md-option ng-repeat="item in PayArr track by $index" value="{{item}}">{{item}}</md-option>
   </md-select>
```

Comment: No problem at all. :)

Comment: @alex_andrea can you help making it work for `ng-options in select`? i tried it was not working

Comment: @nextt1 can you help making it work for `ng-options in select`? i tried it was not working